# Logic with FOR is not working and I do not find the problem

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a logic problem that I have no idea of why this is happening or how to solve it. I have a JSON file that I want to make a change to a value and store in an array

### The JSON file

```
 {
        "info": [
            {
                "actress": "Evan Rachel Wood",
                "actress-id": "162",
                "actress-slug": "evan-rachel-wood",
                "week": {
                    "id": "464",
                    "first": "08/08/18",
                    "last": "20/08/18",
                    "movies": [
                        {
                            "id": "1930500",
                            "titulo": "At imperdiet convallis blandit nisl elementum.",
                            "post_status": "pending",
                            "category": "comedy"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1930499",
                            "titulo": "Porttitor pellentesque imperdiet rutrum.",
                            "post_status": "pending",
                            "category": "drama"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1930498",
                            "titulo": "Quam aenean cursus congue vivamus neque luctus libero quam.",
                            "post_status": "pending",
                            "category": "adventure"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1930497",
                            "titulo": "Sapien ultrices auctor congue enim donec conubia egestas vel senectus",
                            "post_status": "pending",
                            "category": "comedy"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1930444",
                            "titulo": "Imperdiet at inceptos condimentum non dictumst primis interdum",
                            "post_status": "pending",
                            "category": null
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "actress": "Elisabeth Moss",
                "actress-id": "217",
                "actress-slug": "elisabeth-moss",
                "week": {
                    "id": "263",
                    "first": "01/08/18",
                    "last": "10/08/18",
                    "movies": [
                        {
                            "id": "1930443",
                            "titulo": "Rhoncus aliquet proin ut curabitur sit vestibulum feugiat", 
                            "post_status": "pending",
                            "category": "adventure"

                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1930442",
                            "titulo": "Mi himenaeos elementum conubia varius porta habitant hendrerit sociosqu",
                            "post_status": "pending",
                            "category": "drama"

                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1930440",
                            "titulo": "Duis massa maecenas platea purus vel arcu duis vulputate",
                            "post_status": "pending",
                            "category": "action"

                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1930393",
                            "titulo": "Elit semper massa fringilla molestie bibendum, hendrerit",
                            "post_status": "pending",
                            "category": "drama"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

### PHP code

```
$values = json_decode(file_get_contents('json_file.json'), true);

$news = array();

foreach ($values["info"] as $key => $value){

    for($i = 0; $i < count($value["week"]["movies"]); $i++){

        if($value["week"]["movies"][$i]["post_status"] == "pending"):


            $news["actress"] =  $value["actress"];


        $news["actress-id"] = $value["actress-id"];
        $news["actress-slug"] =  $value["actress-slug"];

        $news["week"]["movies"][$i] =  $value["week"]["movies"][$i];

        $news["week"]["movies"][$i]["post_status"] = "draft";



        endif;
                            //$news = $news;
    }

    var_dump($news);
}
```

### What I expected to have to return

```
    array(4) {
  ["actress"]=>
  string(16) "Evan Rachel Wood"
  ["actress-id"]=>
  string(3) "162"
  ["actress-slug"]=>
  string(16) "evan-rachel-wood"
  ["week"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["movies"]=>
    array(5) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(7) "1930500"
        ["titulo"]=>
        string(46) "At imperdiet convallis blandit nisl elementum."
        ["post_status"]=>
        string(5) "draft"
        ["category"]=>
        string(6) "comedy"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(7) "1930499"
        ["titulo"]=>
        string(40) "Porttitor pellentesque imperdiet rutrum."
        ["post_status"]=>
        string(5) "draft"
        ["category"]=>
        string(5) "drama"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(7) "1930498"
        ["titulo"]=>
        string(59) "Quam aenean cursus congue vivamus neque luctus libero quam."
        ["post_status"]=>
        string(5) "draft"
        ["category"]=>
        string(19) "adventure"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(7) "1930497"
        ["titulo"]=>
        string(69) "Sapien ultrices auctor congue enim donec conubia egestas vel senectus"
        ["post_status"]=>
        string(5) "draft"
        ["category"]=>
        string(6) "comedy"
      }
      [4]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(7) "1930444"
        ["titulo"]=>
        string(62) "Imperdiet at inceptos condimentum non dictumst primis interdum"
        ["post_status"]=>
        string(5) "draft"
        ["category"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
  }
}
array(4) {
  ["actress"]=>
  string(14) "Elisabeth Moss"
  ["actress-id"]=>
  string(3) "217"
  ["actress-slug"]=>
  string(14) "elisabeth-moss"
  ["week"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["movies"]=>
    array(5) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(7) "1930443"
        ["titulo"]=>
        string(57) "Rhoncus aliquet proin ut curabitur sit vestibulum feugiat"
        ["post_status"]=>
        string(5) "draft"
        ["category"]=>
        string(9) "adventure"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(7) "1930442"
        ["titulo"]=>
        string(71) "Mi himenaeos elementum conubia varius porta habitant hendrerit sociosqu"
        ["post_status"]=>
        string(5) "draft"
        ["category"]=>
        string(5) "drama"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(7) "1930440"
        ["titulo"]=>
        string(56) "Duis massa maecenas platea purus vel arcu duis vulputate"
        ["post_status"]=>
        string(5) "draft"
        ["category"]=>
        string(6) "action"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(7) "1930393"
        ["titulo"]=>
        string(56) "Elit semper massa fringilla molestie bibendum, hendrerit"
        ["post_status"]=>
        string(5) "draft"
        ["category"]=>
        string(5) "drama"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### But what I have as a return is:

```
array(4) {
  ["actress"]=>
  string(16) "Evan Rachel Wood"
  ["actress-id"]=>
  string(3) "162"
  ["actress-slug"]=>
  string(16) "evan-rachel-wood"
  ["week"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["movies"]=>
    array(5) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(7) "1930500"
        ["titulo"]=>
        string(46) "At imperdiet convallis blandit nisl elementum."
        ["post_status"]=>
        string(5) "draft"
        ["category"]=>
        string(6) "comedy"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(7) "1930499"
        ["titulo"]=>
        string(40) "Porttitor pellentesque imperdiet rutrum."
        ["post_status"]=>
        string(5) "draft"
        ["category"]=>
        string(5) "drama"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(7) "1930498"
        ["titulo"]=>
        string(59) "Quam aenean cursus congue vivamus neque luctus libero quam."
        ["post_status"]=>
        string(5) "draft"
        ["category"]=>
        string(19) "adventure"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(7) "1930497"
        ["titulo"]=>
        string(69) "Sapien ultrices auctor congue enim donec conubia egestas vel senectus"
        ["post_status"]=>
        string(5) "draft"
        ["category"]=>
        string(6) "comedy"
      }
      [4]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(7) "1930444"
        ["titulo"]=>
        string(62) "Imperdiet at inceptos condimentum non dictumst primis interdum"
        ["post_status"]=>
        string(5) "draft"
        ["category"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
  }
}
array(4) {
  ["actress"]=>
  string(14) "Elisabeth Moss"
  ["actress-id"]=>
  string(3) "217"
  ["actress-slug"]=>
  string(14) "elisabeth-moss"
  ["week"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["movies"]=>
    array(5) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(7) "1930443"
        ["titulo"]=>
        string(57) "Rhoncus aliquet proin ut curabitur sit vestibulum feugiat"
        ["post_status"]=>
        string(5) "draft"
        ["category"]=>
        string(9) "adventure"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(7) "1930442"
        ["titulo"]=>
        string(71) "Mi himenaeos elementum conubia varius porta habitant hendrerit sociosqu"
        ["post_status"]=>
        string(5) "draft"
        ["category"]=>
        string(5) "drama"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(7) "1930440"
        ["titulo"]=>
        string(56) "Duis massa maecenas platea purus vel arcu duis vulputate"
        ["post_status"]=>
        string(5) "draft"
        ["category"]=>
        string(6) "action"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(7) "1930393"
        ["titulo"]=>
        string(56) "Elit semper massa fringilla molestie bibendum, hendrerit"
        ["post_status"]=>
        string(5) "draft"
        ["category"]=>
        string(5) "drama"
      }
      [4]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(7) "1930444"
        ["titulo"]=>
        string(62) "Imperdiet at inceptos condimentum non dictumst primis interdum"
        ["post_status"]=>
        string(5) "draft"
        ["category"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the movie arrays of the last array there should be no key [4] that belongs to the first array. I do not see where the problem is. What is wrong with my logic that is making it happen or how to correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this one?

```
$values = json_decode(file_get_contents('json_file.json'), true);

$news = array();

foreach ($values["info"] as $key => $value){
        $news[$key]["actress"] =  $value["actress"];
        $news[$key]["actress-id"] = $value["actress-id"];
        $news[$key]["actress-slug"] =  $value["actress-slug"];

        $movies_array  = array();

        foreach ($value["week"]["movies"] as $key2 => $value2) {

           if($value2["post_status"] == "pending"):
              $movies_array[] = array('id' => $value2['id'], 'titulo' => $value2['titulo'], 'post_status' => 'draft', 'category' => $value2['category']);
           endif;

        }

    $news[$key]["week"]["movies"] = $movies_array;

}

var_dump($news);
```

Comment: This is good and it works. But I'm still going to leave the question open if someone can explain what my logic problem is. I still do not understand why what I did does not work as expected and PHP adds a key that should not exist

Comment: It's because you use var_dump on $news on every iteration without flushing it. On first iteration $news["week"]["movies"][4] has been inserted and it remains for the second iteration - that's why. Just empty $news and it will be ok.